# Is ObjectBox Sync Suit for Membership apps?

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox, objectbox-android, greenrobot-objectbox

I am new to ObjectBox

Let say we have membership apps for customer app which allow customer to order items

**every user using his own phone to order, so in my opinion i don't think it is good to "sync" for  "customer 1" to "customer 2" phone, which is not relevant and useless,**

and if we have 500 customer, and every customer order from his own phone, it will useless to sync the "customer order" between across of device, it only need to sync between client and the server so later on from admin app, admin can process customer order

[image]

If Objectbox suit for this condition, how to implement this case ?, is there any "keyword" need to be specified at model class definition in order to support this situation ?

Comment: Sync is more meant to keep data in sync between server and (all) clients. I guess what you are looking for is some kind of REST API? Also see https://sync.objectbox.io/

Comment: yeah, some kind of it, okay "Sync is more meant to keep data in sync between server and (all) clients". Previously i though it objectbox support specific sync, thank you Uwe, it is clear now

Comment: Do you think objectbox may support that "case" in future sync development ?